# Launching mongodb on Termux error ECONNREFUSED

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, termux

I'm beginner in node.js and trying to run mongodb.
**It works well with remote connection link**, but I have no stable internet connection, so I need to deal with it locally on **Android device + Termux**.
And I haven't found solution of this problem specifically for Termux.

Package npm mongodb is installed.

Just simple connection code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const url = `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myapp`;

mongoose.connect(url)
.then(() => console.log("Connected to mongodb successfully"))
.catch((err) => console.error(err))
```

The error details:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors 
(/storage/emulated/0/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:829:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri 
(/storage/emulated/0/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:804:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { '127.0.0.1:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

Comment: Your code shows only the client side which connects to an existing MongoDB server via network. MongoDB is a server you need to install and run separately. But IMHO Android is not a good platform for Node.JS + MongoDB development. Better get yourself a Linux or Windows PC.

Comment: Package npm mongodb is the driver package, have you installed a mongodb server from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community-edition